# Get First and Last Name By Itself

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need help to get First Name and Last Name separately.

The field is [FullName]: Halsey S Dunn

I could get the FirstName alone but cannot get the LastName by itself:

Here is my code for FirstName and LastName:

```
,SUBSTRING([FullName], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [FullName]) - 1) AS [FirstName]
,SUBSTRING(
            [FullName],1 + CHARINDEX(' ', [FullName]),LEN([FullName])) as [LastName]
```

**My result will need to be:**

```
FirstName- Halsey
LastName- Dunn
```

Comment: What will you do with Spanish double last names?

Comment: If the answer below was satisfactory, you can put closure to your question by marking the answer as accepted. There's a check mark icon beside the answer(s). You can choose to click on the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you can try something like this:

**Example**

```
create table people (fullname varchar(100));
insert into people values ('Harvey S Dunn');
insert into people values ('Tony Mony');
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 

   left(fullname, charindex(' ', fullname)) as firstname,

   reverse(
     right(
        reverse(fullname),
        len(fullname) - nullif(charindex(' ', reverse(fullname)),0)
     )
   ) as fullname_without_lastname,
      
   reverse(
      left(
        reverse(fullname),
        charindex(' ', reverse(fullname)) - 1
      )
   ) as lastname
      
from people;
```

**Result**

> | firstname | fullname_without_lastname | lastname |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Harvey | Harvey S | Dunn |
> | Tony | Tony | Mony |

**Working example you can tweak to your convenience**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed30499b6651f5bfdf5902ba3ee48747